# Can't update add-ons in Android Development Toolkit

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, connection

I have an issue trying to download add-ons of Android from Eclipse.
I get the following error:

"Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason: File not found"

Googling a bit, I found that I need to disable firewall or to set a proxy. However, when I installed Eclipse IDE and the ADT I hadn't this problem. I tryed to fix it setting the router IP as gateway and 80 as port, but I received the same error, but in few milliseconds. Changing the IP to my pc's IP it gives the same issue in some seconds. 
Setting on the option "force https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml to be fetched as http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml" gives the same result.
How can I solve this issue? I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2 on a Ubuntu 10.04.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of ADT are you using?

Comment: Could it be 1.0.26? I retrieved it with adb version

Comment: I checked it, it's the release 12 (july 2011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Eclipse IDE

**Note:** Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) is no longer supported with the latest version of ADT.

so you need to download `Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)  or 3.7 (Indigo)`

[refer here:](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Padma; upgrading to a 3.6 version of Eclipse may cause some dependency issue in Ubuntu 10.04. I'm thinking to upgrade my dist when the new LTS version will be available in a stable way. However, is this the only solution available at moment?

Comment: @user900978 hay you need to download new eclipse version no way to upgrade from 3.5 to upper version. download it and do it http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: ok Padma, thanks for your suggest, you're right, I've no choice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Android SDK is too old. Both linked files simply do not exists (HTTP 404) therefore they can not be downloaded.

The current SDK uses the URLs

- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml

Comment: Hi Robert, I tried to add those links, but the issue remains. I'll try to delete the older one and retry with yours...

Comment: @user900978: You misunderstood me. Not only the download links have changed - the whole SDK downloader application has been updated. Get the latest SDK from Google and install it.

Comment: ok, but as Padma suggested, to change the SDK I need to install Eclipse 3.6 (now I have the 3.5.2 galileo). This could be a problem for dependencies in my Ubuntu, but seems that thre's no alternative ways...